# Which HTTP verb should be used for a combined delete & insert (mimicking and "update")?

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I have sales orders that my customers can submit and then edit at a later date. When inserting the edits into the database, I am choosing to completely remove all line items from the sales order and insert them all again as if it were a new order.

to illustrate:

an initial order of..

```
ORDERID: 1
Lines:
10. item 1 - 45qty
20. item 2 - 50qty
30. item 7 - 33qty
40. item 9 - 65qty
```

then the customer edits the order: (changes qty of item 1, removed item 9 and adds item 4)

```
ORDERID: 1
Lines:
10. item 1 - 60qty
20. item 2 - 50qty
30. item 4 - 10qty
40. item 7 - 33qty
```

My api will first call a SQL command to `DELETE FROM [table] WHERE ORDERID = @OrderID`

then it will loop through *all* the lines from the edit and insert them to the order. Just like it would if it were doing the initial insert when creating a new order.

So my question is...      should i use the HTTP verb UPDATE to do this?  or PUT?  or what would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that HTTP `PUT` is exactly for your case. If you want to update the existing objects then use `PATCH`.

From [REST API design doc](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html):

> The HTTP RFC specifies that PUT must take a full new resource representation as the request entity. This means that if for example only certain attributes are provided, those should be removed (i.e. set to null).
>
> An additional method called PATCH has been proposed recently. The semantics of this call are like PUT inthat it updates a resource, but unlike PUT, it applies a delta rather than replacing the entire resource. At the time of writing, PATCH was still a proposed standard waiting final approval.